# How to eliminate first result from a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say you have a SQL query that is returning `n` results and you want to return only results from `1 to n-1` without first row (0).

Current query is available at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/73895

I want to ignore the first row because it contains an incomplete month.

Update: I simplified the quest, I for removing the last record it is easier by using a WHERE clause based on current date.

Comment: How do you define "first" and "last"? And please specify version of SQL Server.

Comment: What if only one or two rows of data exist?

Comment: Post your query as it is now.

Comment: It's probably easier to just skip the first record in your application code - is that feasible for you?

Comment: Can you provide your query in the first place next time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You changed the question.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col, 
    fr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ordering_col)
  FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT col FROM x
WHERE fr > 1;
```

For the original question (exclude first *and* last row), this is going to incur two sorts:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col, 
    fr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ordering_col),
    lr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ordering_col DESC)
  FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT col FROM x
WHERE fr <> 1 AND lr <> 1;
```